# ParseQueryAdapter - two rows get the same image

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview, parse-platform, recycle

I'm using the ParseQueryAdapter to set up  a listview with data from my Parse sever. I have 3 rows in my table, two doesn't contain an image and one does. If an image doesn't exist on the server, I set my own default image from my resources.
But when the listview finishes its loading, two of the rows have the same image (the one from the server).

*In debug, I see the first two rows get the default image, and only then when I the image from the server is loaded, the first row also get it.

This is my getItemView from the ParseQueryAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getItemView(ParseGame parseGame, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = v;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.shared_games_listview_layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ParseImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewParseImage);
        holder.type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewType);
        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        holder.level = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewLevel);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    super.getItemView(parseGame, v, parent);

    ParseFile photoFile = parseGame.getParseFile("gameImage");
    if (photoFile != null) {
        holder.image.setParseFile(photoFile);
        holder.image.loadInBackground();
    }
    else {
        int width = imageWidth;
        int height = imageHeight;
        if (parseGame.getType().equals(Game.GameType.PUZZLE.toString())) {
            int resId = R.drawable.puzzle_default;
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(imageUtils.getBitmap(resId, width, height));
        }
        else {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the holder:

```
public static class ViewHolder {

    public ParseImageView image;
    public TextView type;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView level;
}
```

What should I do so that each row will get its own image?